# Multiprocessing goes stuck after .get()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand how `multiprocessing` works in python and having some issues.
This is the example:

```
import multiprocessing

def func():
    return 1

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
result = p.apply_async(func).get()
```

When `.get()` function is called, the code is just stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: See **Safe importing of main module** in the multiprocessing [programming guidlelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#programming-guidelines)

Comment: What do you need the get() for? Try to remove it and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these 2 lines inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`

so now your code must look like

```
import multiprocessing

def func():
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = p.apply_async(func).get()
```

If this is being called as an import, it will cause an infinite sequence of new processes. And adding them inside the `if` block works because `if` statement won't execute during import.

Comment: You only need this if the OS is Windows, which is why I asked them what OS they were on

Answer (score 0):

i do not have enough details to know exactly what is the problem.
but i have real strong guess that putting those lines:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
result = p.apply_async(func).get()
```

inside a function will fix your problem.

try this:

```
import multiprocessing

def func():
    return 1

def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = p.apply_async(func).get()
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

tell me if it worked :)